# Running particular quartz job on specific host

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, quartz

I've few quartz jobs that I'm running in clustered mode. Some are IO intensive and some are CPU intensive jobs. What I want to do is run CPU bound jobs on a particular host and run IO bound job on another set of hosts. Is there any configuration where I can whitelist a set of jobs that can run on a particular machine? I don't want to create another set of quartz table do this kind of thing.

Tech: Spring boot, Oracle, Quartz 2.X

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you look at the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470884/quartz-scheduler-how-to-run-a-job-in-only-one-machine/41621260#41621260 look at the comment section about having two different schedulers, IOScheduler, CPUScheduler...

Comment: Thanks, above link looks promising. WIll this work in the clustered environment where all jobs share the same table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did this is to create a different scheduler instance depending on the property passed in JVM startup parameter. I used Spring quartz integration and here is the sample code for that. Most important part is setting of auto startup to false for the scheduler that should not run. This way I was able to create different scheduler but only started the ones that were configured in properties.

```
 @Bean
public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JobFactory jobFactory)
        throws IOException {
    SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    factory.setBeanName("myscheduler");
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factory.setJobFactory(jobFactory);
    factory.setQuartzProperties(getQuartzProperties());
    if (!System.getProperty(SCHEDULER_NAME).contains("myscheduler")) {
        factory.setAutoStartup(false);
    }
    return factory;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest in the Jobstore, just use pauseJob or pauseJobGroup for each jobs for those particular machines.

Or you can also use pause thru SQL

Or thru environment settings, you have a switch there to what jobs you want to get disabled.

Comment: Can you share some info about pause through SQL and pause through environment settings.