# Multiple instances of Quartz scheduler running for multiple servers

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I have one DB which is being used by 3 servers using same code, each of the code has `Quartz scheduler` running. My problem is that all the 3 servers are creating new scheduler instance of scheduler as is visible in `qrtz_scheduler_state` table. And the jobs are scheduled by any instance randomly. I only want one scheduler instance which is used by all the servers no matter which server created that instance, how can I do this. This is my properties file,

```
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=ibScheduler
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=100
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=true
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold=60000
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=false
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.plugin.shutdownHook.class=org.quartz.plugins.management.ShutdownHookPlugin
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.plugin.shutdownHook.cleanShutdown=TRUE
```

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/41621260/175554 and https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/issues/761